# Наложение игры Unity 2d на экран как на скриншотах

Tags: c#, unity3d, windows

Как сделать такой же эффект как на скриншотах? Например чтобы 2д или 3д объект как бы вылезал из окна приложения.[image: скриншот]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта игра была сделана на Unity